# How to hide or make relative the paths that appear in the files inside the conda-meta folder?

Tags: anaconda, conda, relative-path, environment, absolute-path

When a build a conda environment like this

```
conda create --prefix env python=3.6.5
```

Some absolute paths appear in some json files in the `conda-meta` folder. How can I avoid it? I just want to use relative paths here or I just want to hide them completely. Is there a way to achieve this? Are they mandatory? See `extracted_package_dir`, `source` or `package_tarball_full_path` attributes:

```
{
"arch": "x86_64",
"build": "py36_0",
"build_number": 0,
"channel": "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64",
"constrains": [],
"depends": [
    "python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0"
],
"extracted_package_dir": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\pkgs\\certifi-2019.3.9-py36_0",
"features": "",
"files": [
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi-2019.03.09-py3.6.egg-info",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/__main__.py",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/__pycache__/__main__.cpython-36.pyc",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/__pycache__/core.cpython-36.pyc",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem",
    "Lib/site-packages/certifi/core.py"
],
"fn": "certifi-2019.3.9-py36_0.tar.bz2",
"license": "ISC",
"link": {
    "source": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\pkgs\\certifi-2019.3.9-py36_0",
    "type": 1
},
"md5": "e1faa30cf88c0cd141dfe71e70a9597a",
"name": "certifi",
"package_tarball_full_path": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\pkgs\\certifi-2019.3.9-py36_0.tar.bz2",
"paths_data": {
    "paths": [

[...]
```

If I remove the whole folder the environment become useless and I cannot activate it anymore in order to install, update or remove new packages.

I want to do this to encapsulate the environment in one application and I do not want to have my original absolute paths in the computer of the final user.

### My Use Case

I am developing an electron app that uses a tornado server (that uses python)

Currently I am using [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/) to add the environment to the installer and works pretty well, but one drawback is the `conda-meta` folder I commented above. What I do now is to remove it manually when I want to make an installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the best solution I found was to ignore the folder when creating the final installer with `electron-builder`.

So I have applied the directive [`extraResources`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources) to add the conda environment except the folder `conda-meta`. And I have added the filter `"!conda-meta${/*}"`, the meaning is explained [here](https://www.electron.build/file-patterns)

> Remember that `!doNotCopyMe/**/*` would match the files in the `doNotCopyMe` directory, but not the directory itself, so the empty directory would be created. Solution — use macro `${/*}`, e.g. `!doNotCopyMe${/*}`.

The result in the `package.json` file:

```
"extraResources": [
    {
        "from": "../env",
        "to": "env",
        "filter": [
            "**/*",
            "!*.pyc",
            "!conda-meta${/*}"
        ]
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

That will probably break conda.  It's not written to treat those as relative paths.  If you told us more about your use case, maybe we could help.  Are you trying to redistribute an installed environment?  Have you see the "constructor" or "conda-pack" projects?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying [`conda-pack`](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/), but I am facing [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda-pack/issues/66). Anyway the aim of the project seems to package everything into a `tar.gz` file, I wonder if the `conda-meta` still exists inside

Comment: And the [constructor project needs to add channels to the yaml file](https://github.com/conda/constructor#usage), so internet is needed and I wanted to create an offline installer. Currently I am using [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/) to add the environment to the installer and works pretty well, but one drawback is this `conda-meta` folder. What I do know is to remove it manually when I want to make an installer

Comment: I have added these details to my question. I think I will add an instruction to remove the `conda-meta` folder when I build the installers and that´s it. Or even better, I will try to ignore this folder

Comment: Yes, finally the best solution is to ignore the folder, I have answered my own question. Sorry for not explaining my specific use case at the begining :/